# What is the most practical way to express a dependency on a library for which we have a local git repository with some changes?

Tags: git, haskell, dependencies, cabal

The usecase is that I'm having a really hard time testing a fix submitted with [Xmobar `0.47.4`](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/commit/991a168de5d79314a1346a24c579c5049208b054)¹.

I think the reason is that my `.cabal` file

```
executable xmobar
  build-depends: base
               , xmobar
```

is resulting in picking up `0.47.3`, I think because that's the highest tag in the repo at the moment. Indeed,

- if I append `>= 0.47.3` to the last line above, `cabal build`ing works,
- but if I append `> 0.47.3`, then `cabal build` fails because no version satisfies the constraint.

Now, I could obviously ask the author "can you please push the tag too?" (assuming that is enough for `cabal build` to find that new version), but I would like to take this difficulty as an opportunity to learn more about Cabal.

- Can I express a dependency on a specific commit in an online repository?

  This would allow me to use latest changes that have no tag attached, or that are not on the main branch.
- Even better, can I express "the library is not online, but it's at `/home/me/where/I/downloaded/the/repo`

  This, even better, would allow me to easily test local changes to somebody else's repo.

---

(¹) *When using xmobar as a library* and with a cabal project around it to allow *seamless integration with xmonad* (i.e. recompile one recompiles the other, changing either .hs config is picked up when recompiling, and so on; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77817486/5825294) for more details). If I ditch all my setup and leave around only my `~/.config/xmobar/xmobar.hs` and `cabal install` from the local copy of xmobar's repo with the most recent commit checked out, I can see the fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.cabal` file is not the right place for specifying such information: it is associated with a state of the code repository, and shouldn't rely on the presence of any local checkout of other stuff.

Instead, you should put the path to the local install in a `cabal.project` file, namely (in the same directory as your own `.cabal` file):

```
packages: . /home/me/where/I/downloaded/the/repo/Xmobar
```

Then, when you run any `cabal` command it will know to use the local version of `Xmobar` instead of any version currently on Hackage. You can then use the `> 0.47.3` constraint in the `.cabal` file, and only

If only you are working on this project currently, you can simply commit only the `> 0.47.3` dependency to your own Git and keep the local version of `Xmobar` and the `cabal.project` file un-added. It will then be un-compileable for others, but become compileable as soon as Xmobar pushes a new version to Hackage.

Alternatively, you can include your forked `Xmobar` as a [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) into your repo, and add the `cabal.project` file referring to it. Then anybody can check out both your repo and the patched submodule, to build them together.

Comment: Why is the `cabal.project` file the right place? Isn't that something that would be part of the public repo to? Or is it intended to be a file that I maintain separately in a personal repo? As in, why is it ok for `cabal.project` to _rely on the presence of any local checkout of other stuff_?

Comment: Well, as I wrote in the last paragraph the `cabal.project` _could_ also be part of the public repo, but then you must also ensure that the local copy of the dependency is a submodule, else the path to it will be nonsensical to anyone else trying to build your project.